# Parse GraphJSONObjectCallback does not return email

Tags: android, facebook, email, parse-platform

Following [this example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial/issues/35) I have added my 2 keys for Parse + the key for the facebook app.

And when testing the example for android I received the facebook ID and name of the user, but not the rest of fields, like email, gender... Any suggestion I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of GraphJSONObjectCallback method call add the following. You have to pass the fields you want.

```
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email,gender");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
```

Then inside GraphJSONObjectCallback method you can get email and so following way

```
String email = object.get("email").toString();
String gender = object.get("gender").toString();
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:
[Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

Comment: You made my day! Where on earth explain facebook how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my post to include the reference. It's under Graph API.